# Applying same method to multiple objects

Tags: vba, excel

I am curious to know whether there is a way to apply the same method to multiple objects. In other words, I'm looking for something that is, in a way, the inverse of a "With" statement.

I know that using "With" statements, I can apply multiple methods to a single object:

```
With ITEM_RNG
    .ClearContents
    .ClearFormats
    .ClearOutline
End With
```

However, I have multiple range objects to which I would like to apply a single method:

```
ITEM_RNG.ClearContents
VALUE_RNG.ClearContents
SUM_RNG.ClearContents
```

I have tried to create an array of objects to loop with, but it appears to be more convoluted than the above syntax. Is there an way to do this without explicitly appending .ClearContents to each object individually?

Now, using what I've learned about the Union function, I have tried to employ the following, without success.

```
Sub ClearBox(SeriesBox As MSForms.ListBox)
    SeriesBox.Clear
End Sub

Sub SeriesBoxesClearall()
    ClearBox Application.Union(SERIES1_BOX, SERIES2_BOX, SERIES3_BOX)
End Sub
```

Where SERIES[1-3]_BOX are MSForms.ListBox objects. Is there a way to make this work, or does Union not apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Application.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (assuming that all your ranges in the same sheet):

```
Application.Union(ITEM_RNG,VALUE_RNG,SUM_RNG).ClearContents
```

or like this:

```
With Application.Union(ITEM_RNG,VALUE_RNG,SUM_RNG)
    .ClearContents
    .ClearFormats
    .ClearOutline
End With
```

**UPD:**

```
Sub cleanUp(rng As Range)
    rng.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub test()
    Call cleanUp(Application.Union(ITEM_RNG,VALUE_RNG,SUM_RNG))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wonder as well if there is a simple way to run the same function for each object in the union, but varying its input based on the particular object. I assume that this would have to be done by looping through an array, is that correct?

Comment: yeah, in that case you'd better to use array and loop

Comment: It seems that even with a function which only takes a range as its input and is meant to clear the contents, will not accept a union as its argument. Why can a union not be passed?

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, I notice now that when I apply your above edit to Range objects, no problems occur. However, when I try to apply the same method with an MSForms.ListBox object, I run into trouble. Are these objects unable to be handled in the same way?

Comment: OK, I added my code that I'm trying to run for the ListBox, essentially the same form as you showed in your edited answer. Is there a way to make that work? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: as far as I know, only way for you is to use loop..Union works only with Range objects